# Running programs made in C# 4 on a computer that __just__ had .NET framework 4 installed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Is there a wait time between when you can run/install programs made in [Microsoft's VISUAL C# 2010 EXPRESS](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express) and when they would work without errors?

I just installed it on a machine running [Microsoft XP](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/windows-xp) and when I installed my program, it didn't run correctly.  I checked back on my computer, and it ran fine.  Someone mentioned something to me once about needing to wait.???
Is this true?
If so, why?

Comment: No, it will work immediately.  "It didn't run correctly" - what does this mean?  Specific errors?

Comment: Possible related to the ngen service.

Comment: @CodelnChaos What is the ngen service?

Comment: @Joe I'll get specific errors soon.  Sorry, not actually "at" the computer.

Comment: @CodeInChaos It was related to the ngen service.  Add that as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

I think a new install of the Fx requires a restart.

Comment: I'll try that.  Thanks. (Don't worry, if it works, you'll get the credit.)